# jQuery expand/collapse animation 'jumping' past certain height

Tags: javascript, mobile, mobile-website, expander

A simple mobile landing page located here: http://happyappe.com/mms_Mobi

Not sure why, but when the About Us and Products pages are expanded the animation jumps past a certain point. Could anyone give me an idea as to why? Not all too familiar working with javascript.

Appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is due to a known bug and the current workaround is to specify a solid width for the animated element. I tried setting one of your collapsible divs to 280px and the animation smoothed immediately.

Edit: Found what appears to be the bug ticket related to this issue

http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8370

The ticket has been closed and can't be fixed, the comment at the end reads:

> Unfortunately there's not really anything that we can do on our end to divine the right height. Setting the width (as previously mentioned) will achieve the correct result - I recommend doing that in your scripts.

Comment: Thanks so much, really appreciate it. Was hoping I wasn't going to have to set a fixed width, but I guess if thats the only option.